# Writing applications for Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5? (in which IDE, what language)

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-2010, mobile

I am trying to write application for Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5. I never developed anything for WM and have several questions.

First question is about IDE that I will have to use....
Right now, I have Visual Studio 2010. However, when I tried to install Windows Mobile 6.5 SDK, it told me no Visual Studio 2005 or above is found (later I discovered that Visual Studio 2010 only supports development for Windows Phone 7.0 and up, not Windows Mobile 6.5). In this case, I would have to get Visual Studio 2008 to even start development. However, can I use anything else or am I pretty much stuck with having to use Visual Studio 2008?

Next question is what language to use. My first choice was to use Visual C++, however, recently I been reading that Python can be installed and used in Windows Mobile as well. Does anyone has experience working with Python in Windows Mobile (for graphical/GUI applications)? I guess I would still have to use Windows Mobile SDK and Visual Studio 2008 for Python development in Windows Mobile as well?

Comment: I ended up using Visual Studio 2008 Pro and doing development in C# (because of graphical designer for windows forms)

Comment: I also found another option (but it's more problematic to set up) using SharpDevelop(#Develop) IDE: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31861/Windows-Mobile-Development-Without-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Visual Studio 2008 Pro and doing development in C# (because of graphical designer for windows forms).

I also found another option (but it's more problematic to set up) using SharpDevelop(#Develop) IDE:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31861/Windows-Mobile-Development-Without-Visual-Studio