# Windows Mobile 6.1 programming

Tags: windows, visual-studio, rfid, handheld

I have an RFID reader which I want to create a new reader program for. The reader has windows 6.1 mobile - am I still able to use visual studio 2019 to do this or would I have to find and install something like vs 2008?

Is there another alternative?

Comment: Perhaps these articles may be helpful. [Writing applications for Windows Mobile 6.1 and 6.5? (in which IDE, what language)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17449875/9014308), [Building a simple app for Windows Mobile 6.5. Where to start?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40579641/9014308)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: By the way, is the RFID reader built-in? Computers(handheld) with such embedded devices usually have their own SDK, which is strongly dependent on vendor, model, version, etc. Ambiguous questions that do not provide that information will not give the correct answer.

Comment: In general, these articles will be helpful if there are no such special circumstances. [Windows Embedded Compact Development Tools](https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/windows-embedded-compact-development-tools), [Visual Studio compatibility with Win CE 5/6/7 Platform](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-us/01f3442f-91ed-49ff-b316-5f4419ebb837), [Visual Studio Subscriptions](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/subscriptions/), [What software is available for download?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/subscriptions/software-download-list)

Comment: Hi kunif,  thank you for the reply. So the answer is in general no you can't develop the program unless you havea a previous version and or msdn subscription to allow you to download a previous version.